# Update cell value in slickgrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am trying to update the value of a specific cell when a certain key is pressed.
I have so far entered the if-statement in the below code-snippet but I have some trouble when it comes to changing the value of the cell.

```js
var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(e);

if (cell.cell == 6 && e.which == 88) {

    //todo

    this.updateCell(cell.row, cell.cell);
    grid.render();
}
```

Comment: the `render` might not be enough, you should use `grid.invalidate()` instead and perhaps `render` might be unnecessary since if I remember correctly the `invalidate` does internally call `render`. Also I'm not sure what `updateCell` does exactly but it might be just a screen refresh, not an actual item update. It's much easier to use the SlickGrid DataView and that is what I use in all my project, in that case it would be `dataView.updateItem(itemId, item);` and then `grid.updateRow(rowNumber);`

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you know if there is any way where I can use the column and row number instead of the 'itemid'?

Comment: There's `var columnDef = grid.getColumns()[cell]` and `var dataContext = grid.getDataItem(row)` that you can use to find the item before calling the `updateItem(id, item)`

Comment: That was just what I needed. Thanks!